# How to start an incognito web session?

Tags: web-access, webservices, websession

Is this possible to do with `StartWebSession`, in either with Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: There may be a private option some dev here knows about, since you can do this in webdriver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630190/python-selenium-incognito-private-mode/27630230

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @M.R. I'll post the solution I found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple workaround is to tweak to WebUnit`Private`setsession by adding the  **--incognito** arg:

```
setsession[Pattern[sessionInfo, Blank[]], "Chrome", {Rule[Visible, True]}] := post[
    sessionInfo, "/session", {
        "desiredCapabilities" -> {
            "browserName" -> "chrome",
            "chromeOptions" -> {"args" -> {"--incognito"}} (* <= fix *)
       }
    }, {"sessionId", "value"}
]
```

Answer (score 5):

In short, probably not.

There is no default option for this in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartWebSession.html) (as I'm sure you're aware). Without a change to the internals of the function, this probably only leaves you with the option of running e.g. Javascript code via `WebExecute[]`; however, this doesn't seem like it will be fruitful based on discussion in [How to open a page in incognito mode from HTML?](https://superuser.com/questions/1146472/how-to-open-a-page-in-incognito-mode-from-html).

## Javascript test

```
WebExecute["OpenPage" -> "https://www.wolfram.com"]
WebExecute["JavascriptExecute" -> "window.open('https://www.wolframalpha.com', '_blank')"]
```

> ```
> Success["OpenPage", 
> Association[
>  "MessageTemplate" :> "Page `page` opened successfully.", 
>   "MessageParameters" -> Association[
>    "page" -> "https://www.wolfram.com"]]]
> ```

```
WebExecute["JavascriptExecute" -> "windows.create()"]
```

> ```
> Failure["InvalidInput", 
> Association[
>  "MessageTemplate" -> "`command` failed.", 
>   "MessageParameters" -> Association[
>    "command" -> "JavascriptExecute"], "Element" -> "windows.create()"]
>  ]
> ```

## Additional Comments

With an internal change to the function, Chrome could probably be opened in incognito mode [easily](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-run-google-chrome-in-incognito-mode-from-the-command-line-or-a-shortcut/) via `chrome -incognito`, but that may introduce unexpected behavior (i.e. it may not be a quick addition to StartWebSession[] functionality). If you wish to make a feature request, I suggest you contact [Wolfram Support](http://support.wolfram.com/) per the [guidelines on meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1707/61736) and cite this question.